# Change property of sibling element during CSS3 animations

Tags: html, css, keyframe

I want to change the CSS property of an element, from the keyframe animation of a sibling element, say at 50% mark of the animation.

So, something like,

```
@keyframes animname
{
   ....

   50%
   {
       sibling-element{ display:inline;}
   }

   ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. Keyframe animation declarations contain a set of percentages of an overall run-time that define transitions between animatable property states, such as opacity 0 to 1, or left 0 to 200px. A value must be an animatable property to be a valid keyframe value, so a css selector is not permitted. [MDN go into more detail here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

What you can do is trigger two animations on two different elements and time them carefully so that effect is that something happens to the sibling at a certain point in the animation.

[See the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mptfsaom/7/)

```
@keyframes sibling-demo {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    49.9999% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1; 
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1; 
    }
}

@keyframes demo {
    0% {
        width: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

The stripped down code above exposes two keyframe declarations and if they are run on two separate elements one will appear to suddenly happen half way through the other.